# Tooltips with Foundation 5 and SimpleForm

Tags: tooltip, simple-form, zurb-foundation-5

I use SimpleForm with Zurb Foundation 5
(setup as described in https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#zurb-foundation-5).

In my views I can show a Foundation tooltip (e.g. "Type your name") for a form field by writing:

```
= f.input :name, input_html: {title: 'Type your name.', data: {tooltip: ''}}
```

This is nice but it is *too much syntactic overhead*.
How can I configure SimpleForm such that I can use the following *short syntax* in my views for showing the Foundation tooltip:

```
= f.input :name, hint: 'Type your name.'
```

(I've already read https://stackoverflow.com/a/28461799/4096216 but it doesn't help because I don't want a custom tooltip but I'd prefer to use the tooltip provided by Foundation itself, see http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html).

As a workaround I wrote a view helper

```
def hint(text)
  {input_html: {title: text, data: {tooltip: ''}}}
end
```

This allows me to show a tooltip with:

```
= f.input :name, hint('Type your name.')
```

Nevertheless it would feel better/cleaner if I could write:

```
= f.input :name, hint: 'Type your name.'
```

Any suggestions are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into it and ended up implementing a **Custom Component** as briefly described in the [SimpleForm wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-components).

In `config/initializers/simple_form_foundation.rb` I added

```
module SimpleForm
  module Components
    module Tooltips
      def tooltip(wrapper_options=nil)
        @tooltip ||= begin
          hint = options[:hint]

          text =
            if hint.is_a?(String)
              html_escape(hint)
            else
              translate_from_namespace(:hints)
            end

          if text
            <<-HTML
              <span data-tooltip
                aria-haspopup='true'
                class='has-tip'
                data-disable-hover='false'
                tabindex=1
                title='#{text}'>?</span>
            HTML
          end
        end
      end

      def has_tooltip?
        options[:hint] != false && tooltip.present?
      end
    end
  end
end

SimpleForm::Inputs::Base.send(:include, SimpleForm::Components::Tooltips)
```

Which I then could use in the setup part in the same file (some code omitted for sake of brevity):

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.wrappers :vertical_form, ... do |b|
    ...
    b.use :tooltip
  end
...
```

PS: I didn't bother to use SimpleForm's builder to return anything other than a blob of HTML, leaving someone the opportunity to pick it up and show me how do it nicely.

PPS: My example is based on the the more recent Foundation 6.